# Finding unique 9 digit polydivisible number in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Okay so I've not really got a problem with the whole thing, but I need to shorten the runtime, any suggestions? Right now it works but it has an insanely long runtime. I am not a great coder so I need to shorten it a lot. This program is trying to find a 9 digit number, where each digit is unique between 1 and 9, that is also polydivisible. There is only one answer.

```
public int getFirstKDigitNumber(int[] digits, int k) {
    StringBuilder numString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        numString.append(digits[i]);
    }
    int result = Integer.parseInt(numString.toString());
    return result;
}

/**
 * Method to check if the specified number is divisible by the divisor
 * 
 * @param number
 * @param divisor
 * @return true if number is divisible by the divisor
 */
public boolean isDivisible(int number, int divisor) {
    if (number % divisor == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Method to check if 9 digit number is self divisible
 * @param array of 9 digits
 * @return true if number is self divisible
 */
public boolean isSelfDivisible(int[]digits) {
    boolean isSelfDivisible = true;

    for (int j = 1; j<10; j++) {    //check if number is self divisible
        int kDigits = getFirstKDigitNumber(digits, j);
        if (isDivisible(kDigits, j) == false) {
            isSelfDivisible = false;
        }
    }
    return isSelfDivisible;
}

/**
 * Method to create the digit array from the 9 digit int
 * @param 9 digit int
 * @return array of 9 digits
 */
public int[] createDigitArray(int a) {
    String numString = Integer.toString(a);
    int[] digits = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // change the int to an array for
                                    // use by other methods
        digits[i] = numString.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return digits;
}

/**
 * Method to return a list containing all self divisible numbers found
 * 
 * @return 9-digit self divisible numbers
 */
public List<Integer> getSelfDivisibleNumbers() {
    for (int i = 123456789; i <= 987654321; i++) {
        boolean allUniqueDigits = containsAllDigitsOnce(i);
        if (allUniqueDigits == true) {
            int[] digits = createDigitArray(i);
            if (isSelfDivisible(digits)) {
                this.selfDivisibleNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.selfDivisibleNumbers;
}

/**
 * Method to return the number of self divisible numbers found
 * 
 * @return number of 9-digit self divisible numbers
 */
public int getNumberOfSelfDivisibleNumbers() {
    return getSelfDivisibleNumbers().size(); 
}

/**
 * Method to check if 9 digit number contains every digit 1...9 once
 * @param number
 * @return containsAllDigitsOnce
 */
public boolean containsAllDigitsOnce(int number) {
    int num = number;
    boolean containsAllOnce = true;
    int[] oneToNine = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    while (num>0) {
        int nextNum = num%10;
        boolean isValidNum = false;
        for (int i =0; i<oneToNine.length; i++) {
            if (nextNum == oneToNine[i]) {
                isValidNum = true;
                oneToNine[i] = 10;  //change to 2 digit number in case number contains 0
            }
        }
        if (isValidNum == false) {
            containsAllOnce = false;
        }
        num = num/10;           
    }
  return containsAllOnce;
}
```

Comment: It’s a lot of code, and I haven’t seen a `main` method, so I don’t know where it begins. The impression I get from skimming through it is your are generating many numbers and using a lot of time checking those numbers. If this is correct, the solution is called pruning your search: generate fewer numbers.

Comment: I would use specialized code for generating each digit. First observe that the fifth digit must be 5, so you cannot use 5 anywhere else. Now generate from the beginning: the first digit can be any digit except 5. The second can be any even digit except the one you used as the first digit. The third digit needs to make sure that the first three sum to a number divisible by 3, do you see this reduces how many numbers you need to try? For the fourth digit, if the third was even the fourth can be 4 or 8; if odd it can be 2 or 6. Et cetera.

Comment: `381654729` is the only answer in Base 10. There are 1236 solutions in base 17. Starting with `157B4893FDA62GCE`